# PLSQL procedure OUT param - Arrays vs Cursor

Tags: arrays, plsql, cursor

I want to read a OUT param of a PLSQL procedure, to get the list of usernames.[Just a list of names, each name is a String]

This PLSQL procedure can return this Output in 2 ways:

> 1. Return as Array [Table of RAW]
> 2. a Cursor

**My question is** , what is the best datatype of the OUT parameter to be used in the PLSQL procedure? Is it Array or Cursor?

I was told Array is the best one, as You will get the array in one shot when you read the OUT param value. But In the case of Cursor, you just get a handle to the cursor pointer and you infact 'iterate' over it to read next elements.

Please clarify. Thanks

**Update:** Updating with more details for better clarity of the context.

I'm calling this Stored Procedure from a Java program [thru Oracle driver OJDBC], The purpose is to call the SP and get the resultant list of String and display the list in one page. The resultant list will contain an average of 50 and maximum of 100 elements.

Comment: It probably depends on the context.  How and where will the results be used?  If the results are sent to another PL/SQL procedure that will process all records then an array is probably most helpful since PL/SQL understands arrays better.  If the results are sent to a page to display the first X of Y results, a cursor might be best because there's no need to download a million rows if only the first 20 are displayed.

Comment: Let me update the original post for more clarity, Thank you Appreciate that

Comment: From your explanation, I assume that Arrays are more efficient in my scenario. Please post as an answer so that I can accept. Thanks again

Comment: tip: for filling the array use SELECT ... BULK COLLECT INTO instead of looping

Comment: @spiderman I think cursors are more commonly used to pass data to Java, I would guess they are more efficient but I don't have enough experience with either to know for sure.